# NDB Query for empty string in repeated StringProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have ndb modal which have String repeated property. I'm trying to retrieve all the entities which have empty value. But NDB query is returning empty.

```
class A(ndb.model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    values = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)

a1 = A()
a1.name = "T1"
a1.values = ['V1', 'V2']
a1.put()

a2 = A()
a2.name = "T2"
a2.values = []
a2.put()

result = A.query(A.values=="") # Return empty
result = A.query(A.values==[]) # BadValueError: Expected string, got []

for each in result:
  print each.name
```

How do I query the entities which have empty/no values ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to base the query on another field that holds the number of values, e.g.,

```
num_values = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)
```

You'll have to update this number every time you update the `value` field.  Then you can query like this:

```
result = A.query(A.num_values==0)
```

This is similar to another question: [NDB: Sort query results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32567628/584846)